# SQL server separating first name, last name, and middle initial permanently

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has first name, last name, and middle initial, when there is one, in one column like this:

```
Name
Doe, John B
Smith, Bob
```

Some names do not have a middle initial and I just want to get rid of the ones that do. So far I have this query:

```
SELECT   [table].[Name]
    ,LEFT([table].[Name], CHARINDEX(',', [table].[Name]) - 1) AS [Surname]
    ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING([table].[Name], CHARINDEX(',', [table].[Name]), LEN([table].[Name])), ',', '') AS [FirstName]
FROM    [table]
```

Which gives me this result:

```
Surname  First Name
Doe      John B
Smith    Bob
```

Is there something that I can add to just get rid of the middle initial when it occurs? Also, can I permanently change this data so it remains in two separate columns?

Comment: You need software for this, because you'll have never-ending exceptions, like `Elizabeth van der Nutz`, `James van Gundy III`, `Philip de la Casta, ESQ.`, `Madonna`, and `The artist formerly known as Prince.` The software is expensive for a reason: data cleansing is hard.

Comment: For splitting a string on a delimiter in SQL (provided input strings < 8000 bytes) check my earlier answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72292/splitting-a-csv-column-from-select-query-into-multiple-columns/72298#72298

Comment: Is there a way to cut off the middle initial by looking to see if there is a space in the string and delete anything after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Query:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT Name, LEFT(Name,CHARINDEX(',',RIGHT(Name,LEN(Name)-CHARINDEX(',',Name)))+CHARINDEX(',',Name)-1) AS [Last] FROM table)
SELECT [Last], LEFT(REPLACE(Name,Last+', ',''),CHARINDEX(' ',REPLACE(Name,Last+', ',''))-1) AS [First],
       RIGHT(REPLACE(Name,Last+', ',''),LEN(REPLACE(Name,Last+', ',''))-CHARINDEX(' ',REPLACE(Name,Last+', ',''))) AS Middle
FROM CTE
```

This uses a CTE for clarity and it also accounts for many special cases including names with suffixes (Jr, Sr, Esq, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format is strictly `Last, First <Optional initial>` for first without initial:

```
SUBSTRING([table].[Name], CHARINDEX(',', [table].[Name]) + 2, 
    LEN([table].[Name]) - CHARINDEX(',', [table].[Name]) 
    - CASE WHEN PATINDEX('% [A-Z]', [table].[Name]) > 0 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END)
```

If you want to permanently change it, create a query with what you want and overwrite the values.